# Why is my specific css code changes not being reflected on my browser?

Tags: html, css, django

So, I have a specific css code for my badge message notification that is not being updated when I mess with it. The rest of my css, form styles.css are working. When I edit them, the changes are reflected. Even when I move my badge css code over to `styles.css` the changes are still not reflected. They are indeed showing up when I inspect element, but not being reflected in the browser. I tried emptying the cache, doing a hard reload, etc. but nothing seems to be working. I am guessing there is something overriding my badge code? When I first made it, I had 0 problems editing it. I must of added something in the meantime. My badge should be showing up as white instead of red, and it should be far higher than it is, but it's not moving and it's still the same color as when I originally made it.

**base.html/header**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
```

**base.html/badge**

```
  <a class= text-danger  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css"      class="notification"> 
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                            <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
```

**notification.css**

```
  .notification {



  text-decoration: none;
  padding:50;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}



.notification .badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -25px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white !important;
  color: white;
}
```

**settings.py**

```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dating_app/static"),
]
```

**project urls**

```
    urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('dating_app.urls', namespace= 'dating_app')),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**directory**

```
    .
├── 11_env
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── activate
│   │   ├── activate.csh
│   │   ├── activate.fish
│   │   ├── django-admin
│   │   ├── django-admin.py
│   │   ├── easy_install
│   │   ├── easy_install-3.7
│   │   ├── pip
│   │   ├── pip3
│   │   ├── pip3.7
│   │   ├── python -> python3
│   │   ├── python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
│   │   └── sqlformat
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python3.7
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── dating_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── chat.html
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── profile_photo
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20200410_2231.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20200411_2011.py
│   │   ├── 0004_auto_20200413_1930.py
│   │   ├── 0005_auto_20200413_1946.py
│   │   ├── 0006_auto_20200413_2222.py
│   │   ├── 0007_auto_20200422_1947.py
│   │   ├── 0008_auto_20200425_0039.py
│   │   ├── 0009_auto_20200426_1957.py
│   │   ├── 0010_auto_20200426_2005.py
│   │   ├── 0011_auto_20200426_2005.py
│   │   ├── 0012_auto_20200426_2007.py
│   │   ├── 0013_auto_20200427_1846.py
│   │   ├── 0014_auto_20200503_1947.py
│   │   ├── 0015_auto_20200503_2011.py
│   │   ├── 0016_auto_20200511_0104.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── js
│   ├── tag.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── dating_app
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── unread_messages_counter.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── dating_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**base.html**

```
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}



{% load unread_messages_counter %}





<!-- Navbar is located in this file -->


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>


    {% block head %}
    <title>Base</title>
    {% endblock %}

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>

<style>





</style>
</head>
<body>


    <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light  ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class= 'navbar-brand'  href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}"><h5 style="color:red"></h5> </a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse"  id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto" >


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class= text-danger  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css"      class="notification"> 
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                            <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}

                    <li class="nav-item">

                        <a class= text-danger   href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}






                  <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class= text-danger href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                  </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class=text-danger  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                   </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class=text-danger href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                   </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class=text-danger href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                   </li>






            {% else %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class= text-danger href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class= text-danger href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
     <div>

    </nav>

    </div>



 <!--
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top ">
     <div class = 'nav-wrapper'>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}" /></a>
                </li>



            </ul>

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}

                    <li>
                        <a ref = 'stylesheet'   href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css"  class= text-white  class="notification"> 
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                            <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}
                    <li>
                        <a ref = 'stylesheet' class= text-white   href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">  
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% endif %}






                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link"  class= text-white href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" class= text-white  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" class= text-white  href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" class= text-white  href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                </li>






            {% else %}
              <div>
                <a href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">log in</a>
                <br>
                <a href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
     <div>
    </nav>

    -->


<!-- HEADER AREA END -->


<!--Below is individual page will html will be rendered -->

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
<h1 id="h1"> Hello world</h1>

<!-- FOOTER AREA BEGINS BELOW-->

<footer class="container">

</footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself...

You are missing quotes around the first text-danger class and you have two class attributes:

```
<a class="text-danger notification"  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css"> 
<span>Inbox</span>
<span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I had figured it had something to do with that, but I was still having an issue getting the red color to appear WITH my badge color being a separate thing.. I didn't know I needed to put my notification inside with my 'text-danger'. Why is that? How come it doesn't work if I put notification into it's own class

Comment: notification is its own class, and you can have has many classes as you want per element, but you can only have one class ATTRIBUTES (or fields) per element. So with class="text-danger notification", you can style it using .text-danger OR .notification. Or if you just want that one element you can do .text-danger.notification

Comment: I need to learn front end. I have spent 2 years working on python and django, do you have any recommendations for where to learn front end stuff?

Comment: Honestly, I think the best way to learn is to just do. I learnt by making mistakes and trying to fix it (I made the exact same two class= mistake just a week ago). That said, I would also recommend looking at a Udemy course, they tend to be good starting points for things like CSS. Oh, and get familiar with bootstrap - makes everything so much easier: https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: bootstrap is what I'm using. Thanks!

Comment: Learn bootstrap over pure css?

Comment: Learn both, they're not mutually exclusive. Pure CSS is important though just to understand how it all works and how to manipulate it. You can learn it in a day though. Then it's just about getting it wrong...then getting it right

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. Say, I'm having a problem on my background image in Jumbotron, think you can take a quick look? Just posted the question